# Anorm query, flatten not found

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

In the yabe example, there is this query :

```
   def allWithAuthor:List[(Post,User)] = 
            SQL(
                """
                    select * from Post p 
                    join User u on p.author_id = u.id 
                    order by p.postedAt desc
                """
            ).as( Post ~< User ^^ flatten * )
```

In my app, I have a very similar query :

```
def findAll:List[(Album,Artist)] = 
      SQL(
       """
           select * from Album al
           join Artist ar on al.artist_id = ar.id
           order by al.nbVotes desc
           limit 100
       """
      ).as( Album ~< Artist ^^ flatten * )
```

I have this compile error :

```
The file /app/models.scala could not be compiled. Error raised is : not found: 
value flatten Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

I don't find the difference with the yabe working example...

Do you why I have this error?

Comment: oh yes you're right! 
I needed to import play.db.anorm.SqlParser._

thanks :)

Comment: i was confused between List.flatten and the parser one

Comment: Your welcome ! And good luck for your Scala journey :)

Comment: Try to post your answer and accept it plz. Important for the Playframework tag statistics! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, add

```
import play.db.anorm.SqlParser._
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, but `import anorm.SqlParser._` did!